# Unable to connect hosting provider MYSQL database in asp.net

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, linq, asp.net-4.0

I have MYSQL database from Hosting provider net4.in and i am unable to access database.

My code is as below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class dummy : System.Web.UI.Page
{
 OdbcConnection conn;

    string Address = "Driver={MySql ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=phpmyadmin7.net4india.com;Option=3;Port=3306;Stmt=;" +
              "DataBase=test;Uid=demo;Pwd=demo123;";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sql = "Select * from test.testing limit 5";
        DataSet rsDSet = new DataSet();
        try
        {
            if (sql == "") throw new Exception("SQL input required");
            conn = new OdbcConnection(Address);
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) conn.Open();
            OdbcDataAdapter adp = new OdbcDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            adp.Fill(rsDSet);

        }
        catch (Exception ee)
        {
            Response.Write(ee.ToString());
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = rsDSet;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Pl let me know how can i connect MYSQL DB.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What's going wrong ? Got an error ? A timeout ? A segfault ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your MySQL instance is hosted on a machine named phpmyadmin7? It seems unlikely. Phpmyadmin is the name of a chunk of client software, as I am sure you know.

Are you sure your hosting provider allows access from outside their data center to MySQL server instances? (Presuming you are running the sample code you provided from your own machine, which might not be the case.) Most hosting providers protect their MySQL instances from internet-wide access because it is easy to mount DDOS attacks against them otherwise.

In some hosting provider environments the MySQL authentication scheme only allows access to your MySQL instance from the particular machine upon which your web apps run.

In any case you need to have a conversation with your support crew about how to do this.